# Laravel Auth problems, can't login as Auth::attempt returns false

Tags: authentication, laravel

I have 2 forms "registration" and "login".

The `UserController.php` that handles both registration and login is as follows:

```
    public function store()
      {
            $data = new User;
            $data->Username = Input::get('username');
            $data->email = Input::get('email');
            $data->password = Hash::make((Input::get('password')));
            $data->save()
            // redirect
            return Redirect::to('users');
      }

      public function postSignin() 
      {
            $userdata = array(
                'email' => Input::get('email'),
                'password' => Input::get('password')
            );

            if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
                dd('success');
            } else {
                dd('error');
            }
        }
```

Registration works and saves password hashed, but when I try to login it always displays `"string(5) "error"`.  Where may be the problem?

My `routes.php` is as follows:

```
Route::get('users', 'UserController@index');
Route::post('users/register',array('uses' => 'UserController@store'));
Route::post('users/signin',array('uses' => 'UserController@postSignin'));
```

EDIT:

```
$userdata = array(
                'email' => Input::get('email'),
                'password' => Input::get('password')
            );
 if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
                dd('success');
            } else {

                // validation not successful, send back to form 
                 dd($userdata);
            }
```

and displays

```
array(2) { ["email"]=> string(15) "admin@gmail.com" ["password"]=> string(5) "admin" }
```

isn't it decrypting the paassword? because always performs else condition

Comment: Hi. Same trouble here.How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you store method **username** and **password** in your registration.

whereas in your login method you check for **email** and **password**.

Comment: changed it. and still the same problem. I added $data->email = Input::get('email'); at registration and still shows error

Comment: what am I missing ? pls any idea?

Comment: i assume your `User` model does implement `Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface`?

Comment: it was used, i was looking at the wrong model. so it uses Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;  and still doesn't log me in. Also changed field pass to 60 chars and still the same problem